# SPF Record Not Working - Doesn't Show Up at All

Tags: email, dns, sendgrid, amazon-route53, spf

Recently, emails being sent by my webapp are being marked as spam by Gmail.  Possibly other providers as well.  My webapp uses Sendgrid to send some system-related automated or user-triggered emails.  When I first encountered this issue, I set up an SPF record within Amazon Route 53 that solved the problem.

About a week ago, these system emails started going into spam again.  When I go to dmarcian.com and use their SPF Surveyor tool, the tool says that I do not have an SPF record for the domain.

I double-checked my dashboard in Sendgrid and the SPF records are verified on that end.  I also set up link branding, added the requisite DNS records in Route 53, and verified them through Sendgrid.  That did not fix the issue.

Here is the SPF record I have in Route 53:

v=spf1 mx a include:sendgrid.net -all

I have tweaked this from what is was previously in attempts to get this to work.  It previously did not include the "mx a" tags but still provided the desired results.

I'm expecting these emails to show up in my regular inbox without a huge warning banner telling me they could be spam.  Currently the emails arrive with that banner, or they just go straight to my spam folder and I have to mark them in both instances as not spam.

I'm a complete novice at this stuff, so if there's something I didn't include someone needs to see, please just let me know and I'll post whatever is needed.

Comment: Look at the headers in gmail ("show original"); does it actually say that the SPF checks have failed?

Comment: Here's what it says regarding SPF and DKIM in the email header:

SPF: PASS with IP X.X.X.X Learn more
DKIM: 'PASS' with domain sendgrid.me Learn more

Note that I changed the IP, it's giving an actual number in the header.

Comment: OK, so google is happy with your SPF. Is it an actual `SPF`-type record, or is it a `TXT` type (the former is deprecated)? Try checking [here](https://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html?). We can't do any diagnostics without knowing the actual domain, but I'd also say that gmail's spam filter is pretty terrible; you will often end up in spam even if you have correct SPF, DKIM & DMARC passes.

Comment: Adding the actual header text:

ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@sendgrid.me header.s=smtpapi header.b=RrCcaiGs;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces+912999-79ec-tim=certassurance.com@sendgrid.net designates x.x.x.x as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="bounces+912999-79ec-

Comment: So it is an SPF record, I wasn't aware that was deprecated.  I'll change it to TXT and see what happens.

Comment: The SPF type was obsoleted in [RFC7208](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-3.1), which replaced the original RFC4408.

Comment: Bingo!  Now the SPF record is coming back as validated.  However, emails are still showing as spam.  I guess it takes some time to percolate through to gmail?

Comment: In my experience, it's probably gmail filtering on the basis of history, reputation, and content, something that it's extremely bad at. If you have sufficient sending volume, you could see if their [postmaster tools](https://postmaster.google.com) have something to say about your status.

Comment: Looks like what I had to do was add myself as a contact in gmail.  Solved the problem for me but makes me worry about all the other gsuite users out there.

Thanks for the help!